# Web Scraping - Titles

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used to webscrape titles from websites but this time I cannot do it and  don't know why.
You can see my code, below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import ssl
from time import sleep
from random import randint
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
    
html = urlopen("https://officialblackwallstreet.com/directory/")
bsObj = soup(html.read())
bws_titles_bags = []
bws_names = bsObj.findAll(["a","title data-original-title"])
```

**Result**

```html
<img alt="" class="attachment-javo-tiny size-javo-tiny wp-post-image" height="80" sizes="(max-width: 80px) 100vw, 80px" src="https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-80x80.jpg" srcset="https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-80x80.jpg 80w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-150x150.jpg 150w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-300x300.jpg 300w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-768x768.jpg 768w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-600x600.jpg 600w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-250x250.jpg 250w, https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Newport-Avenue-Ocean-Beach-McClean-Photography-132x133.jpg 132w" width="80"> </img></div>
</a>, <a href="https://officialblackwallstreet.com/biz/zmena-inc/">
<div class="img-wrap-shadow">
```

How can I retrieve, for example the title " McClean Photography" , and the other ones ?

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on "I can not do it anymore" ? What results are you expecting and what results are you actually getting ?

Comment: If the front-end is built with React, you might want to use Selenium instead of BS4

Comment: @MarleneHE   Thank you for your reply.  I want to retrieve the company names of a page web "https://officialblackwallstreet.com/directory/". I used to use this code to retrieve data from a website but it does not work for this website. The result that I have is too long for the comment section

Comment: If you are web scraping websites that update dynamically (ie react, angular or even sites without framework that do api calls), you will either have to access the data directly by making an http request to their API(sniff the network in chrome dev tools) or use selenium to simulate a browser and retrieve your data that way.

Comment: Ok thank you all. I will try with selenium :)

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically via Ajax from other URL. You can use this example to get the titles:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = 'https://officialblackwallstreet.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

params = {
    'post_type':  'item',
    'type':    2,
    'page':    1,
    'ppp': 9,
    'action':  'post_list',
    'order':   'DESC',
    'orderby': 'date',
    'keyword': ''
}


data = requests.post(api_url, data=params).json()

#uncomment this to print all data:
#print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for m in data['markers']:
    print(BeautifulSoup(m['info']['post_title'], 'html.parser').text)
```

Prints:

```
McClean Photography
Zmena INC.
Hippie Adjacent
YourAdminOnline.com
Don’t Sweat The Technique
Asanee Coaching Services
Joy Street Design
Natural Ash Body
```